# How to periodically evaluate page with Nightmare JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm using Nightmare JS to load a page and I want to run some code periodically within the scope of the page.
Here's what I have right now:

```
const Client = Nightmare({ show: true, switches: { "proxy-server": proxy } })
  .goto(url)
  .then(() => setInterval(() => Client.evaluate(() => test()), 4000))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

And I always get the following error: `TypeError: Client.evaluate is not a function`

However, the following code works fine, no matter how many evaluate statements I add:

```
const Client = Nightmare({ show: true, switches: { "proxy-server": proxy } })
  .goto(url)
  .evaluate(() => test())
  .evaluate(() => test())
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I really can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try separating the declaration and commands: `const Client = Nightmare(...);` then `Client.goto(url)...`.

Comment: @ChrisG Client.evaluate seems to return an empty page when I call it from the interval from what I can tell (i.e. console.log(document) does nothing from inside the interval, while it does print something in the main chain)